# Angular 8: Leaflet map is undefined when we leave and enter back to page

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

In my ngOnInit lifecycle, I create a map using leaflet.

HTML

```
 <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
```

TS

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';


  ngOnInit() {
  this.map = map('map').setView([38.914764662971436, -97.01461108304595], 13);


    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }).addTo(this.map);
}
```

After that, I load some data and display icons using just `L.marker...addTo`..and all that works fine.
Issue happens when I go to some other page, and then re-enter the previous page which has the leaflet map, the map is loaded and I can see it, but no icons are created and `this.map` variable is `undefined`.

Do I need to somehow remove the map completely on `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle? It seems like leaflet keeps the map in memory or something and then reuses it instead of creating a new one.

Here is a Stackblitz demo..weird enough...it works there even tho I created samoe code..
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leaflet-map

Comment: Can you provide a demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @kboul provided

Comment: Just remove the `setTimeout` function. Why do you need it? Just call `addMarkers()` without using it. Also `map` is not undefined if you log it inside `ngAfterViewInit` [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leaflet-map-kry2cq?file=src/app/leaflet-map/leaflet-map.component.ts)

Comment: setTimeout was used to mimic the async thats used in my real world app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue was not in creating the map.

What happened was due to getting data before map was created:

First time opening the component:

- Data is loaded from API and saved in store in async manner
- Map is created
- Data is fetched after the map is created so then the markers are added

Second time opening the component:

- Instead of calling the API, data is fetched from store
- Data is fetched before the map is created
- Map is created
- No markers are displayed as no map is created

What did I do to fix it? Waiting for the map to be created before adding the terminals.

Answer (score -1):

you should use AfterViewInit just like in your example

Comment: I did use it there.